# Hiding text and links for unregistered users in Magento

Tags: magento

Can I hide some text in Magento category pages for unregistered users, I have some text with a button at the bottom of every page, if there is a way to hide this text and button, it will be very good, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    //customer is logged in
}else{
 //guest user
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shivam for your reply, just a question, I am pasting my page as html only, how I can use this code inside html? thank s again

Comment: are you using custom template ? or list.phtml?

Comment: I am doing my html in separate file and then I copy and paste it in admin category "General Information" field here is the page: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/sacs-reutilisables/sac-toile-de-jute.html

Comment: Please elobrate. in which feild?

Comment: if description the please open file [magento]\app\design\frontend\[default]\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml line 56

Comment: replace code for $_description condition
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Thanks Shivam, your solution hides the full page, but what I need is part of the page only, can I do that? Thanks Again

Comment: Instead of saving html data in database. Create phtml file that contains both html as well PHP code.and call it in category view.phtml.

Comment: can you tell me please how to call phtml in category view.phtml, Thank you very much

Comment: I used static block and add that to category, but how to use your code inside my new phtml file, I always get error when I add anything instead of //customer is logged in